# Local notifications won't show up on device?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, notifications, local, device

I made an iphone app for my girlfriend and it works fine on my iphone.
On her's iphone too except the local notifications won't show up.
The app also won't show up in the notification center of the iphone settings itself.
I searched for differences in my iphone settings and her's but I can't find the problem.

I did not paste my notification code because I think the problem lays somewhere else..

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is she using iOS 8?  If so, make certain you call [UIApplication's `registerUserNotificationSettings:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerUserNotificationSettings:) method so the app can display local notifications.

You can determine if it worked by adding a [`application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:) method to your app delegate.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
I'm a newby when it comes to the AppDelegate stuff.
Do I have to put something in that method or is putting 
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {   
}
down, enough?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You can override that method in your app delegate to figure out whether the registration was successful.

Comment: I did that but the notification still will not show up :(

Comment: Yep! I let the app ask to use local notifications, and it automatically showed up in the iphone settings itself too!